# php cron replacement

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cron

I have some php script `updater.php` which does some job for 1-2 minutes. Finishing the script job is important.

I can run it with cron, but i have some idea.

Script will run concrete time only when user gets for example home page. In this case it's unnecessary to execute script every time, only when it's needed.

So, user loads `http://localhost/index.php`, js script post small get request:

```
$.get('/json/updater.php', function(data){ return true; });
```

Requests proceed good in 1-2 minutes.

The question: Will processing of `updater.php` work stop, if user closes the tab in browser and therefore break $.get request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requests don't get cancelled if you close the browser window, so PHP will simply be able to complete the script (**assuming the execution time doesn't exceed the maximum configured time** See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). Of course, anything you do in JavaScript will stop once you close the window.

Comment: Well, you do have to open the browser every now and then... But yes, if all you want to do is execute a script at random times, it's a good replacement.

Comment: @AlexanderKononenko: It's not a "replacement" for `cron` by any means.  `cron` does something entirely different.  `cron` schedules jobs to run at regular intervals.  What you're doing is running a job in response to an event.  If it gets the job done, that's great.  But it's not an alternative to `cron`.

Comment: Yes, only execution of script is important! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind you can execute PHP scripts directly from the command line or with cron, just use the path of your PHP interpreter. For scheduled jobs I would recommend not having any fronted requirements (JavaScript/Browser) as this can cause consistency issues, you want your job to run every 2 minutes without fail and adding another step (AJAX or Browser) introduces the possibility for that frequency to become inconsistent.

Comment: I understand. I have no access to shell (or even I have, i dont need to run script every 2 minutes, I have to run it only to update ratings of some data + log script starting time and wait 10 minutes (for example) till next script execution. Just check time difference. If more than 10 minutes - update. Plus if there is no users on the site -> there is no load on server).

Comment: Most hosting providers will give you access to the crontab via CPannel  or another server management interface, your best bet would be to check with them.

If you don't require the operations to be run in the background (ie: no users active on the site) then you should be fine with using the method you'r using, just be aware you have to take into account (JavaScript) that a request within the browser may time-out or not even reach the server.

Answer (score 1):

> Will processing of updater.php work stop, if user closes the tab in browser and therefore break $.get request?

Only if they close the tab before the request is actually sent, which would be fairly quickly, in which case it wouldn't "stop" but would rather "never have started."

Once you receive the GET request from the client, the request itself is done.  You can spawn a process on the server and the browser has no control over that.  The browser can only stop client-side code from running.

Conversely, why do this on a separate request?  If you want the process to be spawned when the page is loaded, why not spawn it from *within* `index.php`?  The benefits would include:

- The process runs even if the user has JavaScript disabled.
- The process runs even if the user cancels navigation before the JavaScript code is loaded/run in the browser.
- Slightly less network overhead, since there would be only one request to the server.

Comment: 1. In my project js is required, so i can do this via ajax.

Comment: 2. Did you mean, in index.php add the job? or calling of needed script?

Comment: @AlexanderKononenko: Yes, just run the code when index.php loads instead of having the client-side code of index.php make a second call to run the code.  That way it happens with only one request.

Comment: Hmm.. i have to test it. Thanks!